# Navigator.clipboard copy doesnt work on Safari when the copy text is grabbed via asynchronous call

Tags: javascript, safari, clipboard, navigator

I have a react file, using a copyText with navigatorClipboard and documentExec command. However in Safari both are not working when the call is wrapped up with asynchronous mode.
Here is an example created in codesandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-worker-rypyr?file=/src/App.js

```js
  
    let textArea;

const isOS = () => navigator.userAgent.match(/ipad|iphone/i);

const selectText = (text) => {
  textArea = document.createElement("textArea");
  textArea.value = text;
  document.body.appendChild(textArea);

  if (isOS()) {
    const range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(textArea);
    const selection = window.getSelection();
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
    textArea.setSelectionRange(0, 999999);
  } else {
    textArea.select();
  }
};

const copyToClipboard = () => {
  const success = document.execCommand("copy");
  console.log(success);
  document.body.removeChild(textArea);
};

const copyExecText = (text) => {
  selectText(text);
  copyToClipboard();
};

const copyNavText = (text) => {
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(text).then(
    () => {
      console.log("Async: Copying to clipboard was successful!");
    },
    (err) => {
      console.error("Async: Could not copy text: ", err);
    }
  );
};

export { copyExecText, copyNavText };

    
    const wait = (ms) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

  
  const makeCopyText = async () => {
    await wait(1000);
    copyNavText("Non Sync copy text with Navigator!");
  };

  const makeCopyTextExec = async () => {
    await wait(1000);
    copyExecText("Non Sync copy text with exec!");
  };
```

```html
<div>
        <button onClick={makeCopyTextExec}>Async Copy Exec Text</button>
        <button onClick={makeCopyText}>Copy Nav Text</button>
        </div>
```

Ideally, I am trying to get the copy context from an API (Async way) and put that in the clipboard. Safari rejects both the function straightaway and I am unable put the content in the Clipboard. However both Chrome and Firefox works fine.

Please let me know is there any way to make the Safari works on Asynchronous mode.

Comment: Please insert the relevant code in the question itself. And no, if you are not handling an user gesture at the time you perform the request Safari won't let you write to the clipboard. You would need to perform the async request before the user interacts with the page (or ask them to interact twice).

Comment: did you ever figure this out? Experiencing the same problem

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem with Safari and it seems that there are not workarounds:

> The implementation is available through the `navigator.clipboard` API
> which must be called within user gesture event handlers like
> `pointerdown` or `pointerup`, and only works for content served in a
> secure context (e.g. `https://`). Instead of a permissions-based model
> for reading from the clipboard, a native UI is displayed when the page
> calls into the `clipboard` API; the clipboard can only be accessed if
> the user then explicitly interacts with the platform UI.

Source: https://webkit.org/blog/10247/new-webkit-features-in-safari-13-1/